# Boton submit formularios

Tags: html, formularios

me gustaria saber si puedo hacer que el boton de submit "", utilizarlo de enlace hacia otra pagina. Darle a mandar y a la vez de darle a mandar me rediriga a otra pagina diferente.
Si me podeis ayudar, lo agradeceria mucho.
Saludos!

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Pon un ejemplo de lo que estas haciendo donde se vea el boton y el formulario, y dinos la página donde lo quieres mandar. No se entiende si quieres mandarlo a otra página directamente (con lo cual un enlace es suficiente) o bien quieres mandarlo a un archivo PHP para que procese el formulario y despues este te reenviara a otra página si el proceso sale bien (es lo normal si usas un submit)

Comment: @masterguru no lo mando a ninguna pagina, son archivos locales nada mas.

Comment: Pues no se entiende lo que pretendes, la verdad, explicate mejor.  Edita tu pregunta con un ejemplo de lo que estas haciendo ahora y asi podremos ver lo que quieres hacer, sino tenemos que imaginarnos cosas que no sabemos y podemos estar divagando dias.